# springboot2.6: defer-initialization-mode set to true: data.sql is not initialized

Tags: spring-boot-2.6.0

I am upgrading my springboot from 2.2 to 2.6. As part of this upgrade, when I am testing JUNITs using inMemory H2 database, all tests started failing with missing data despite having data.sql.
I reviewed spring docs and made following changes in my application.yml file.

```
spring.sql.init.mode: always
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization: true
spring.jpa.generated-ddl: true # tried this option without hibernate one too
spring.jpoa.hibernate.ddl-auto: create-drop #tried this option alone too along with changing to create
```

Despite using above options, I dont see my data.sql data visible in test cases and all my test cases started to fail.Did anyone encounter similar issue? If so, what would be possible resolution?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change your data.sql to import.sql

Comment: I didn't need to change the name. "import.sql" is for Hibernate, isn't it?